# Bash Script stuck looping

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, syntax

I'm trying to write a script that runs another script which fails rarely until it fails.

Here is the script that fails rarely:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))

if (( n == 42 )) ; then
        echo "$n Something went wrong"
        >&2 echo "The error was using magic numbers"
        exit 1
fi

echo "$n Everything went according to plan"
```

Here is the script that should run the previous script until it fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

script_path="/tmp/missing/l2q3.sh"

found=0
counter=0

while (( $found == 0 )); do
        output=(bash $script_path)

        if (( $output == 42 Something went wrong )); then
                found=1
        fi

        ((counter++))

if (( $found == 1 )); then
        echo "Number 42 was found after $counter tries"
fi

done
```

when I try running the second script I get stuck in an infinite loop saying there is a syntax error on line 11 and that something is wrong with `42 Something went wrong`. I've tried with `"42 Something went wrong"` aswell and still stuck in a loop.

Comment: `(( ))` is for arithmetic operation in bash, so that script will surely fail...

Comment: `output=(bash $script_path)` creates an array named `output` and assigns 2 values; `typeset -p ouput` ==> `declare -a output=([0]="bash" [1]="/tmp/missing/l2q3.sh")`; the follow-on test `$output == 42` will then end up trying to compare `bash` to `42` (`$output` == `${output[0]}`) which will always be false so you'll never run `found=1` and hence get stuck in the loop forever

Comment: I'm *assuming* what you want is something like `output=$(bash $script_path)` but then you get into a mix of issues with what's being passed back from `$script_path` (ie, strings of output from `echo` calls) and how the parent script is supposed to parse/process those strings (stored in `$output`)

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you it was a mixture of this and comparing with (( )) instead of [[ ]]

Comment: You shouldn't be testing strings at all!  Test the value returned by the script.  It will work to simply write `while output=$(bash "$script_path"); do ...; done`.  The loop will terminate when `script_path` returns non-zero.

Comment: Learn to copy/paste problem code into https://shellcheck.net and fix anything that is flagged. If its still not working, then post a question here. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or similar) as your first line when using shellcheck. Good luck.

Comment: As long as a `while` loop is not working as planned, keep a `sleep 1` (or `sleep 0.1`) in the loop. When the end condition of the loop is failing, don't make the computer crazy.

Answer (score 1):

The form `(( ))` is *arithemetic* only, so you cannot test a string inside.

To test a string, you have to use the `[[ ]]` version:

```
[[ $output == "42 Something went wrong" ]] && echo ok
ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the program execution *as* the test for a while/until/if (etc.)

Assuming your script returns a valid 0 error code on success, and nonzero on any other circumstance, then -

```
$: cat tst
#!/bin/bash
trap 'rm -fr $tmp' EXIT
tmp=$(mktemp)
while /tmp/missing/l2q3.sh >$tmp; do let ++ctr; done 
grep -q "^42 Something went wrong" $tmp &&
  echo "Number 42 was found after $ctr tries"
```

In use:

```
$: ./tst
The error was using magic numbers
Number 42 was found after 229 tries
```

Answer (score 0):

here are 3 steps to move forward.

1. add a return value at the end of the first script

`exit 0`

2. make your first script has executable rights

`$ chmod a+x /tmp/missing/12q3.sh`

3. instead of while loop you may use until, which would run until it returns success i.e. 0

   `until /tmp/missing/l2q3.sh; do ((counter++)) done`

for other if statements please use square brackets [ single or double [[.